# ConversionException with Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, otto

I am working with Retrofit and Gson Converter but I get this weird Exception. I am using two URLs to perform the call. In both cases I do the same call and get the same response in the full-log level, but one of the URLs gives me this Exception and I can't parse data in the second case.

Using Retrofit v1.9 and Gson v2.6.1.

Thanks!

Error:

```
E/UserCommunicator: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expecting character, got:
     retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expecting character, got:
         at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:378)
         at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
         at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
         at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
         at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expecting character, got:
         at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:67)
         at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:362)
        ... 7 more
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expecting character, got:
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:397)
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:388)
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879)
         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844)
         at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63)
        ... 8 more
E/LoginActivity: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expecting character, got:
```

Json from server:

```
{
    "user_data": {
        "user_id": "4",
        "gid": "",
        "gname": "",
        "gphoto": "",
        "fid": "",
        "fname": "",
        "fphoto": "",
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "birthday": null,
        "registered": null,
        "username": null,
        "user_type": "a",
        "rnd": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "user_lang": "en",
        "clinic_name": null,
        "clinic_id": null,
        "admin": null,
        "state": null,
        "gender": "",
        "cel": "60000000"
    },
    "clinic_data": {
        "clinic_name": "Doe",
        "clinic_id": "2",
        "plan": "plan",
        "mod_finance": "0",
        "mod_surgery": "0",
        "mod_ortodoncy": "0",
        "staff_type": "staff_type",
        "admin": "0",
        "state": "state",
        "address": "address",
        "latitude": "0.0",
        "longitude": "0.0",
        "cel": "",
        "nr_licenses": null,
        "expires": null
    },
    "response": "Success"
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have created two classed to decode above json

Comment: It's nice you included the error, but you have valid JSON, so the problem is your code, which you haven't shown. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

Your GSON objects are probably wrong. You can [generate Java classes based on your JSON for GSON](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ClinicData {

    @SerializedName("clinic_name")
    @Expose
    private String clinicName;
    @SerializedName("clinic_id")
    @Expose
    private String clinicId;
    @SerializedName("plan")
    @Expose
    private String plan;
    @SerializedName("mod_finance")
    @Expose
    private String modFinance;
    @SerializedName("mod_surgery")
    @Expose
    private String modSurgery;
    @SerializedName("mod_ortodoncy")
    @Expose
    private String modOrtodoncy;
    @SerializedName("staff_type")
    @Expose
    private String staffType;
    @SerializedName("admin")
    @Expose
    private String admin;
    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    private String state;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private String latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private String longitude;
    @SerializedName("cel")
    @Expose
    private String cel;
    @SerializedName("nr_licenses")
    @Expose
    private Object nrLicenses;
    @SerializedName("expires")
    @Expose
    private Object expires;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The clinicName
     */
    public String getClinicName() {
        return clinicName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clinicName
     *     The clinic_name
     */
    public void setClinicName(String clinicName) {
        this.clinicName = clinicName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The clinicId
     */
    public String getClinicId() {
        return clinicId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clinicId
     *     The clinic_id
     */
    public void setClinicId(String clinicId) {
        this.clinicId = clinicId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The plan
     */
    public String getPlan() {
        return plan;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param plan
     *     The plan
     */
    public void setPlan(String plan) {
        this.plan = plan;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The modFinance
     */
    public String getModFinance() {
        return modFinance;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param modFinance
     *     The mod_finance
     */
    public void setModFinance(String modFinance) {
        this.modFinance = modFinance;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The modSurgery
     */
    public String getModSurgery() {
        return modSurgery;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param modSurgery
     *     The mod_surgery
     */
    public void setModSurgery(String modSurgery) {
        this.modSurgery = modSurgery;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The modOrtodoncy
     */
    public String getModOrtodoncy() {
        return modOrtodoncy;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param modOrtodoncy
     *     The mod_ortodoncy
     */
    public void setModOrtodoncy(String modOrtodoncy) {
        this.modOrtodoncy = modOrtodoncy;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The staffType
     */
    public String getStaffType() {
        return staffType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param staffType
     *     The staff_type
     */
    public void setStaffType(String staffType) {
        this.staffType = staffType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The admin
     */
    public String getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param admin
     *     The admin
     */
    public void setAdmin(String admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The state
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param state
     *     The state
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param address
     *     The address
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The latitude
     */
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param latitude
     *     The latitude
     */
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The longitude
     */
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param longitude
     *     The longitude
     */
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The cel
     */
    public String getCel() {
        return cel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param cel
     *     The cel
     */
    public void setCel(String cel) {
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The nrLicenses
     */
    public Object getNrLicenses() {
        return nrLicenses;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param nrLicenses
     *     The nr_licenses
     */
    public void setNrLicenses(Object nrLicenses) {
        this.nrLicenses = nrLicenses;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The expires
     */
    public Object getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param expires
     *     The expires
     */
    public void setExpires(Object expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }

}


@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("user_data")
    @Expose
    private UserData userData;
    @SerializedName("clinic_data")
    @Expose
    private ClinicData clinicData;
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private String response;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The userData
     */
    public UserData getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userData
     *     The user_data
     */
    public void setUserData(UserData userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The clinicData
     */
    public ClinicData getClinicData() {
        return clinicData;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clinicData
     *     The clinic_data
     */
    public void setClinicData(ClinicData clinicData) {
        this.clinicData = clinicData;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The response
     */
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param response
     *     The response
     */
    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}

public class UserData {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("gid")
    @Expose
    private String gid;
    @SerializedName("gname")
    @Expose
    private String gname;
    @SerializedName("gphoto")
    @Expose
    private String gphoto;
    @SerializedName("fid")
    @Expose
    private String fid;
    @SerializedName("fname")
    @Expose
    private String fname;
    @SerializedName("fphoto")
    @Expose
    private String fphoto;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("surname")
    @Expose
    private String surname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("birthday")
    @Expose
    private Object birthday;
    @SerializedName("registered")
    @Expose
    private Object registered;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private Object username;
    @SerializedName("user_type")
    @Expose
    private String userType;
    @SerializedName("rnd")
    @Expose
    private String rnd;
    @SerializedName("user_lang")
    @Expose
    private String userLang;
    @SerializedName("clinic_name")
    @Expose
    private Object clinicName;
    @SerializedName("clinic_id")
    @Expose
    private Object clinicId;
    @SerializedName("admin")
    @Expose
    private Object admin;
    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    private Object state;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;
    @SerializedName("cel")
    @Expose
    private String cel;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userId
     *     The user_id
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The gid
     */
    public String getGid() {
        return gid;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param gid
     *     The gid
     */
    public void setGid(String gid) {
        this.gid = gid;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The gname
     */
    public String getGname() {
        return gname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param gname
     *     The gname
     */
    public void setGname(String gname) {
        this.gname = gname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The gphoto
     */
    public String getGphoto() {
        return gphoto;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param gphoto
     *     The gphoto
     */
    public void setGphoto(String gphoto) {
        this.gphoto = gphoto;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The fid
     */
    public String getFid() {
        return fid;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fid
     *     The fid
     */
    public void setFid(String fid) {
        this.fid = fid;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The fname
     */
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fname
     *     The fname
     */
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The fphoto
     */
    public String getFphoto() {
        return fphoto;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fphoto
     *     The fphoto
     */
    public void setFphoto(String fphoto) {
        this.fphoto = fphoto;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     *     The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param surname
     *     The surname
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param email
     *     The email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The birthday
     */
    public Object getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param birthday
     *     The birthday
     */
    public void setBirthday(Object birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The registered
     */
    public Object getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param registered
     *     The registered
     */
    public void setRegistered(Object registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The username
     */
    public Object getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param username
     *     The username
     */
    public void setUsername(Object username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The userType
     */
    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userType
     *     The user_type
     */
    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The rnd
     */
    public String getRnd() {
        return rnd;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param rnd
     *     The rnd
     */
    public void setRnd(String rnd) {
        this.rnd = rnd;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The userLang
     */
    public String getUserLang() {
        return userLang;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userLang
     *     The user_lang
     */
    public void setUserLang(String userLang) {
        this.userLang = userLang;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The clinicName
     */
    public Object getClinicName() {
        return clinicName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clinicName
     *     The clinic_name
     */
    public void setClinicName(Object clinicName) {
        this.clinicName = clinicName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The clinicId
     */
    public Object getClinicId() {
        return clinicId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clinicId
     *     The clinic_id
     */
    public void setClinicId(Object clinicId) {
        this.clinicId = clinicId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The admin
     */
    public Object getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param admin
     *     The admin
     */
    public void setAdmin(Object admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The state
     */
    public Object getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param state
     *     The state
     */
    public void setState(Object state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The gender
     */
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param gender
     *     The gender
     */
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The cel
     */
    public String getCel() {
        return cel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param cel
     *     The cel
     */
    public void setCel(String cel) {
        this.cel = cel;
    }
}
```